# Query returning every row null in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pusher

I'm trying to build a chat application using laravel echo and pusher, everything works but the data that returns to the databse is either null or the default value, here's the code

```php
public function sendMessage(Request $request){
    $conID = $request->conID;
    $message1 = $request->message;
    $user = Auth::user();

    $fetch_userTo = DB::table('messages')
        ->where('conversation_id', $conID)
        ->where('user_to', '!=', Auth::user()->id)
        ->get();
    $userTo = $fetch_userTo[0]->user_to;

    $message = Message::create([
        'user_from' => Auth::user()->id,
        'user_to' => $userTo,
        'conversation_id' => $conID,
        'message' => $message1,
    ]);

    if($message) {
        $userMsg = DB::table('messages')
            ->join('users', 'users.id','messages.user_from')
            ->where('messages.conversation_id', $conID)->get();

        broadcast(new MessagePosted($message))->toOthers();
        return $userMsg;
    }
}
```

NB: when i put insert() instead of create in the query the data goes through the database normally but there's an error in broadcasting

Comment: Try to test conditions in your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create a message like this? instead of using a model event?

```
$message = new Message;

$message->user_from = Auth::user()->id;
$message->$user_to = $userTo;
$message->conversation_id = $conID;
$message->message = $message1;

$message->save();
```

You have a lot more control this way, i.e

```
if($message->save()) { ... }
```

Or you could wrap the whole thing in a transaction?

Be sure your Message model allows the fields that you want to add in the $fillable array

Comment: I tried it and it worked thank you, but I'm testing this application just to learn that's why I still wan't to know why the create() doesn't work hahah

Answer (score 0):

Create method check fillable attributes into Laravel model. You have to write your all columns into fillable and then use create method.

Second solution is use Active Record technique. @Devin Greay answer is helpful to use Active record.

More information visit https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: I did have every column in a protected fillable